# Почему вызывается событие mouseMoveEvent при клике на ComboBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.8

При воспроизведении данного примера на `Python 3.8 32bit` (`PyQt 5.14.1`) событие `mouseMoveEvent` срабатывает. А на Python 3.8 64bit (PyQt 5.14.1) - не срабатывает, как и должно. Версии PyQt одинаковые. С чем это может быть связано и как лечить?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Demo(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()

        vbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        cb = QComboBox()
        cb.addItem("Первый")
        cb.addItem("Второй")
        
        vbox.addWidget(cb)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w  = Demo()
    w.resize(300, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: т.е. вы нажимаете левой кнопкой мышки на отображаемый текущий элемент `QComboBox`
и вместо того чтобы получить раскрывающийся список элементов вы получаете 
`print(event)`, я  вас правильно понял или надо проделать какие-то другие действия ?

Comment: И список раскрывается, и print(event) отрабатывает. А нужно только открытие списка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему таким образом:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.pressing = True

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.start = event.globalPos()
    self.pressing = True

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.pressing:
         print(event)

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
    self.pressing = False
```

Comment: что-то я не вас не совсем понимаю, вы говорите что добавили `mouseReleaseEvent `, а `mousePressEvent` - откуда взялся ?

Comment: Ну он нужен для дальнейшей работы с позицией окна, а установка флага и фильтра по нему устраняет проблему отработки mouseMoveEvent при клике на ComboBox. Но почему так на 32bit среде происходит - так и не понял.

Answer (score 1):

я не смог смоделировать то, что вы описываете. Запустите мой пример и понаблюдайте, что у вас происходит.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Demo(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.cb = QComboBox()                    # + self.
        self.cb.addItem("Первый")
        self.cb.addItem("Второй")
        vbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.cb)
        
        self.cb.installEventFilter(self)         # +  
        self.cb_flag = False                     # +

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.cb_flag:                     # +
            print(event.globalPos())
        
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):           # +++
        if obj == self.cb and event.type() == QEvent.Enter: 
            self.cb_flag = True
            print(f'1   eventFilter {self.cb_flag}')
        elif obj == self.cb and event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            self.cb_flag = False
            print(f'22  eventFilter {self.cb_flag} --- {event.type()}')
        else:
            print(f'333 eventFilter {self.cb_flag} --- {event.type()}')
            
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w  = Demo()
    w.resize(300, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @WD_KMS enum QEvent::Type https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил событие mouseReleaseEvent и через флаг получилось устранить проблему